# Save changes in datagridview to textfile

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, text-files

I have read the data from textfile in the datagridview now i want to make changes to the  textfile if datagridview values are changed by the user at runtime?
this is my code for reading the file now i want to update data in text file at that particular location and write it..

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line = "";
        string text = "";
        bool si = false;
        int w = 0;
        bool t = false;
        bool counter = false;
        int length = 0;
        const Int32 BufferSize = 128;
        int groupid = -1;
        int stringid = -1;
        string[] split;
        int tnog = 0;
        if (file.Contains("random.TST"))
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(this.file))
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains('$') && (line.Contains('@') || line.Contains('}')))
                    {
                        split = line.Split(' ', '@', '}');
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains('$'))
                    {
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains('|'))
                    {
                        counter = false;
                    }
                    else if (!(counter))
                    {
                        split = line.Split(' ', '@');
                        for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (t)
                            { }
                            else if (!t)
                            {
                                if (split[i].Trim() == "")
                                {
                                    groupid = 0;
                                }
                                else if (split[i].Trim() != "")
                                {
                                    groupid = Convert.ToInt16(split[i]);
                                    t = true;
                                    tnog++;
                                }
                            }

                            counter = true;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (counter)
                    {
                        //split = line.Split(' ');
                        if (line.Contains('|'))
                        {
                            counter = false;
                        }
                        else if (counter)
                        {
                            split = line.Split(' ', '@', '}');
                            for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
                            {
                                if (si)
                                {
                                    if (split[i].Trim() == "")
                                    {
                                        //text[i] = " ";
                                    }
                                    else if (split[i].Trim() != "")
                                    {
                                        text += Convert.ToString(split[i]);
                                        text += " ";
                                        length = text.Length;
                                    }

                                }
                                else if (!si)
                                {
                                    if (split[i].Trim() == "")
                                    {
                                        // sid[i] = 0;
                                    }
                                    else if (split[i].Trim() != "")
                                    {
                                        stringid = Convert.ToInt16(split[i]);
                                        si = true;
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            if ((groupid == -1) || (stringid == -1))
                            { }
                            else
                            {
                                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(groupid, stringid, text, length);
                                text = "";
                                if (tnog % 2 == 0)
                                {
                                    dataGridView1.Rows[w].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                                    dataGridView1.Rows[w].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    dataGridView1.Rows[w].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Plum;
                                    dataGridView1.Rows[w].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
                                }
                                w++;
                            }

                            si = false;
                            t = false;
                        }


                    }
                }
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(tnog);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid File:");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you [tried first](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) ?

Comment: i have posted my reading code.but i dont know where to start with the writing part.

Comment: Rather than trying to insert your changes into the text file, just create a brand new file from the contents of your datagridview.

Comment: i thought of that too but the file has a specific format.When i am reading the file i ignore certain characters..thats why i cannot generate a new file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should look into binding your data to the datagridview (can you give us some sample rows from the file?), but if not...

Read your entire file into a string and replace all relevant values with a unique placeholder counter, i.e {1}, {2}.  Replace placeholder counters with datagridview data before writing string back to file.

Comment: 3 @ data   :@
    4 @ data  :@
    5 @ data   :@
    6 @ data  :@
    1 @  data :@
  100 @  data :@
    8 @ Units file name - Input :@       this is the file data..the numeric values are ids and the data is the text..How can we tell which rows has the user updated?and how can i bind data to the gridview?any examples?

Comment: Create a DataTable and populate that instead of populating the DataGridView directly.  Then set dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable.  [Here is an example of databinding.](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?592638-RESOLVED-Delimited-Text-to-Datagridview-problem-with-tab-and-space-delimiters)